# Combobox's Dynamic event in flex

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, events

I am using flex when i was select combobox item i want to create new form 
for eg. when i select 1 it will appear one form when i select 2 it will appear 
two.so and so....

Comment: Go back to your old questions and select the green check mark near the post that best answers your question to accept them. But unless you rephrase/expand/provide some code, you are not gonna get much help with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your Forms inside of a ViewStack container. You can then bind the ViewStack's selectedIndex to the selectedIndex of your ComboBox:

```
<mx:ComboBox id="comboBox" />

<mx:ViewStack selectedIndex="{comboBox.selectedIndex}">
    <mx:Form id="formA">
        ...
    </mx:Form>
    <mx:Form id="formB">
        ...
    </mx:Form>
</mx:ViewStack>
```